# Criteria in grails

Tags: grails, criteria

Could you tell me what's wrong in my Criteria here?

```
    def users
    def u = User.createCriteria()
    users = u.list (max: max, offset: offset) {

        eq("account",account)

        and {

            if(teacherName != null && teacherName != ""){
                like("userName", "%"+teacherName+"%")

            }

            if(mobileNumber != null && mobileNumber != ""){
                like("mobileNumber", "%"+mobileNumber+"%")

            }

            eq("status", Status.ACTIVE)
            eq("userType","Account Teacher") 
        }


    }
    return users
}
```

the list returned empty why?

Comment: You should describe your data model and what do you wanna get .

Comment: It's very difficult to say what the problem is without seeing the `User` domain class

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is unnecessarily verbose. An equivalent implementation is:

```
def users = User.withCriteria(max: max, offset: offset) {

    eq("account", account)

    if (teacherName) {
        like("userName", "%${teacherName}%")
    }

    if (mobileNumber) {
        like("mobileNumber", "%${mobileNumber}%")
    }

    eq("status", Status.ACTIVE)
    eq("userType", "Account Teacher") 
}
```

I can't say why this isn't working because I don't know what the `User` domain class looks like or what behaviour the query is supposed to exhibit, but it ought to be easier to debug a more concise implementation.